# How to prevent user from making in-app purchases by sending unauthorized requests to Apple/Google?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

Let's say I have a pack in my mobile app that can only be bought 3 times total. So after it has been bought those 3 times, the user is no longer allowed to buy more of this specific pack (the button is greyed out). How can I prevent someone from sending unauthorized requests to Apple/Google to continue buying more of these packs?

I am inexperienced in these regards but I heard it is technically possible for someone to do this provided that they have access to the app's source code, which I assume anyone can have.

Any help appreciated